# Counting invites for new members

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

I'm trying to get the possible invite for users that join on discord But it simply doesn't work and I don't know why. I'd expect it to output "couldn't find invite" for bots but instead it says nothing at all, not for users, nor bots. It should work to my knowledge. It scans every invite in the servers and stores them, then it checks if it goes up on the user that joins and outputs the embed.

```
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.get_invites())

    async def get_invites(self):
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                try:
                    guild_invites = {}
                    invites = await guild.invites()
                    for invite in invites:
                        guild_invites[invite.code] = invite
                    self.invites[guild] = guild_invites
                except discord.errors.Forbidden:
                    pass


    async def find_possible_invites(self,guild):
        i = 1
        while i < 11:
            new = await guild.invites()
            res = []
            for invite in new:
                try:
                    old_uses = self.invites[guild][invite.code].uses
                except KeyError:
                    self.invites[guild][invite.code] = invite
                    if invite.uses >= 1:
                        res.append(invite)
                    continue
                new_uses = invite.uses
                if old_uses < new_uses :
                    self.invites[guild][invite.code] = invite
                    res.append(invite)

            if res == []:
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                i+=1
            else:
                break
        return res

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self,member):
        server = await self.bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)
        possible_invites = await self.find_possible_invites(server)
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

        whtspace= "** **"
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x21d3f3)
        embed.title = "Member Joined!"
        embed.add_field(name="Name",value=str(member))
        embed.add_field(name="User ID:",value=member.id)
        if len(possible_invites) == 1:
            embed.add_field(name="Invite used",value=possible_invites[0].url,inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Invite created by",value=str(possible_invites[0].inviter),inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Number of uses",value=str(possible_invites[0].uses),inline=True)

        elif len(possible_invites) > 1:
            embed.add_field(name="Possible invites used:",value=whtspace,inline=False)
            for i in possible_invites:
                embed.add_field(name=whtspace,value=i.url,inline=False)
        else:
            await channel.send("Invite used could not be detected")

        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `i` in `find_possible_invites`?